# in Flutter, what is the difference between .addListener(nofityListeners) and .notifyListeners?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, listener, flutter-routes

I am not even sure xxManager.notifyListeners() is valid because what I saw so far is just plain notifyListeners() being used in class that extend ChangeNotifier for example :

```
 Timer(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
      () {
        _initialized = true;
        notifyListeners();
      },
    );
```

here i tried to understand the meaning of

```
class AppRouter extends RouterDelegate<AppLink>
    with
        ChangeNotifier,
        PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin {
  @override
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  final AppStateManager appStateManager;
  final XXManager xxManager;
  final YYManager yyManager;

  AppRouter({
    required this.appStateManager,
    required this.xxManager,
    required this.yyManager,
  })
      : navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>() {
    appStateManager.addListener(notifyListeners);       <-------This part
.
.
.
}
```

that part of the code for what I understand is to add listener to see the change in appStateManager which if changes will trigger notifyListeners method. what i dont understand is when i change it into:

```
appStateManager.notifyListeners();
```

it didnt show any error but when I ran it apparently it does not listen nor notify (the appStateManager has a Timer function which change the state in this case isInitialized to true after 2s so if the listener catch it, it will "route to next widget" (hope i said it correctly)).
with 1st case it will change screen after 2s but on 2nd case it does nothin.
what is wrong?

Comment: also will notifyListeners() even listen to the change in appState? i think that's why it does not work huh? but is there any purpose of sticking it to manager or any other thing? what can it does?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward.
`appStateManager.addListener()` adds listeners.
`appStateManager.notifyListeners()` notifies those listeners.

But with this line:
`appStateManager.addListener(notifyListeners);`
You are adding listeners with the name `notifyListeners`. `notifyListeners` is a variable here. It's not the same as the method

Comment: thank you for your response! what will trigger the 2nd case appStateManager.notifyListeners() to work in this case? and also isn't a notifyListeners a listener too? so i initially thought by sticking it in appStateManager it will magically listen to the change in state and notify the other listener, is it wrong? haha

Comment: @dxdx I'm actually not familiar with `AppStateManager`, I have no idea when or how it notifies the listeners

Comment: could you give me an example in what case manager.notifyListeners() will work? it does not have to be AppStateManager. my AppStateManager only consist of state variables in which if it changes will call notifyListeners(),

Answer (score 0):

addListener is register a closure to be called when the object changes.

notifyListeners is Calling all the registered listeners.

Note that:

- with addListener, if you want to add an instance, then it must be removed the same number of times it is added before it will stop being called.
- these methods must not be called after dispose has been called.

Comment: for example : AppStateManager.addListener(func) then i defined the void func(){notifyListeners(); print('asdf');}, the first one works but the print('asdf') is not executed becasue i didnt see asdf in console. so is it true addListener is only to execute Listeners?

Comment: Just put the print function before notifyListeners(); and it'll work.

Comment: i put the print function before and after the notify listener. it does not work but somehow when i run it in browser mode it works and print both. i will try to investigate it again. thank you very much!